# Komma in dem Satz

Tags: sentence-structure

Ist dieser Satz richtig?
ich bin nicht sicher mit dem **Komma** nach Kinder.

> Durch diese Aktivität lernen die Kinder, viele kreative Ideen zu entwickeln und sie umgehend umzusetzen.

Verbesserungsvorschläge sind  auch willkommen.

Comment: Nein, das Komma ist falsch.

Comment: +1, da der Downvoter nicht seinen/ihren Downvote erklärt hat.

Comment: -1, da @c.p. aus falschen Gründen +1 verteilt.

Comment: +1 weil ich die Frage gut und ontopic finde.

Comment: Bitte die Frage nicht ändern, wenn es schon Antworten gibt.

Answer (score 5):

Hier werden keine Kommas benötigt:

> Durch diese Aktivität lernen die Kinder viele kreative Ideen zu
>   entwickeln und sie umgehend umzusetzen.

Hinter `Kinder` ist das Komma optional, da es sich um einen erweiterten Infinitiv in seiner einfachsten Form (2x) handelt.

Comment: `viele Kreative Ideen zu entwickeln und sie umgehend umzusetzen` ist eine "simple" Infinitivgruppe. Das Komma nach `Kinder` ist also optional. Ich habe meine Antwort um diese Info ergänzt.

Comment: In der ursprünglichen Frage war - bevor sie mehrmals editiert wurde - enthalten, ob nach `zu entwickeln` ein Komma von Nöten sei. Da dieser Teil der Frage gelöscht wurde, entferne ich dementsprechend auch den Teil meiner Antwort...

Comment: Dabei wäre der Punkt durchaus ein für den Lerner interessanter Aspekt: Endete der Satz leicht abgewandelt auf ".. und setzen sie umgehend um", so müsste man vor "und" genau dann zwangsweise in komma setzen, wenn man das optionale vor "viele" setzt.

Answer (score 4):

Das Komma ist richtig. Als ich zur Schule ging, hieß das ein „erweiterter Infinitiv mit ‚zu‘“, und das Komma war bei einem solchen vorgeschrieben. Inzwischen ist es meines Wissens optional, aber bei einem so langen würde ich immer noch immer eines setzen.